# OptaPlanner, DRL error, accumulating longs getting double

Tags: drools, optaplanner

My first OptaPlanner project, to assign tasks to workers. When launching the app got following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.optaplanner.core.api.solver.SolverManager]: Factory method 'solverManager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: There are errors in a score DRL:
Error Messages:
Message [id=1, kieBase=defaultKieBase, level=ERROR, path=com....taskassignment/TaskAssignmentRules.drl, line=7, column=0
   text=Rule Compilation error The method addSoftConstraintMatch(RuleContext, long) in the type HardMediumSoftLongScoreHolder is not applicable for the arguments (RuleContext, double)]
```

The Task class is like this:

```
public class Task {
    ...
    private long durationInSec; // how long the task takes
    ...
}
```

want to have a fairness rule, so that all workers have the similar total durations, the DRL is here:

```
package com.....taskassignment;
import org.optaplanner.core.api.score.buildin.hardmediumsoftlong.HardMediumSoftLongScoreHolder;
import com.....domain.*;

global HardMediumSoftLongScoreHolder scoreHolder;

rule "fairness"
    when
        $worker : Worker(name != null)
        accumulate(
            Task(worker == $worker, $d : durationInSec);
            $s : sum($d*$d)
        )       
    then
        scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, -$s);
end
```

Don't understand why $s is a double? If the last line is like:

```
scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, -1);
```

then no error showed up. How can I fix this? I use HardMediumSoftLongScore because I think double is slower than long.

Answer (score 1):

this fixed the issue

```
scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, -$s.longValue());
```